npm install -g grunt-cli seems to work but then command not found
I have installed grunt using npm install -g grunt-cli, then it only write:

changed 56 packages in 4s

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details


And when I try using grunt afterward grunt --version it says: bash: grunt: command not found
I have try adding it to my path manually, but there is no npm directory under C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming
If I do npm ls -g then I get this output:
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Volta\tools\image\node\20.15.1
├── corepack@0.28.1
├── grunt-cli@1.5.0
├── grunt@1.6.1
└── npm@10.7.0


How do I fix this?

Did you restart your terminal after install. Try exec zsh on macos

according to your bash output it is in the users/{username}/AppData/Local... directory, not Roaming.  On my machine my bash output also shows libraries in the node_modules directory that is a subdirectory of the path shown in the npm ls -g command.  The PATH value you need to add should be in the AppData/Local directory you have shown, and possibly in a node_modules or even npm/node_modules subdirectory.

Actually I didn't succeed at running it globally, but I succeeded at running yarn run grunt [my command].
